# Mouse issues on second screen

Tags: mouse, garageband

I recently started facing a weird bug on my macbooks. Whenever I connect an external screen through a hub there are issues with the mouse. In some apps (Descript) I can't 'click' certain buttons despite my cursor hovering over them, in some apps (Zoom) the app thinks my mouse is elsewhere and thus does not display the buttons, in same apps (Garageband) I can't stop dragging once I start dragging.

This happens on two independent macbooks.

Were there any recent updates to how the mouse behaves on OSX on external screens?

Comment: Do you use the hub on both MacBooks? What happens if you connect the monitor directly to the MacBook?